# How can I make two versions of an app and let both share the same settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I've got a paid version with a bundle identifier `com.openfrog.appName` and I believe it's not possible to use the same bundle identifier for two apps.

For a number of good reasons I don't want to use In-App Purchases so having two separate apps is a good solution for me. One paid. One free.

What must I do in order to let the paid version inherit the settings of the free version? I remember there was a trick or rule you had to follow in order to make sharing of NSUserDefaults beetween two apps possible. What's the trick to let both apps share the same settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use addSuiteNamed: method of NSUserDefaults.

```
- (void)addSuiteNamed:(NSString *)suiteName
```

This will work only for reading settings, not for writing.

See ref -

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> "The suiteName domain is similar to a bundle identifier string, but is
>   not tied to a particular application or bundle. A suite can be used to
>   hold preferences that are shared between multiple applications."

Comment: With this, one app can read the settings of another if the settings have been registered with the same "Suide"? So all I have to do is add the same suite name in both apps?